# Accuracy assessment {greenbrown} - which is classified, which one is reference?

Tags: r, classification, landsat

I want to **assess the accuracy** of the land cover classes classified by supervised classification of Landsat images. As reference data I use the aerial photography.

I sampled the classified Landsat data and at the same validation point, I identified the land cover class from aerial photography. I.e., each of my verification points have two attributes: one from Landsat (*landsat*), second from the aerial photography (*reference*).

I want to calculate an error matrix (contingency table), and accuracy assessment (overall accuracy, user's producer's accuracy) from the set of verification points.

I found a package *greenbrown* and *asbio* to assess the accuracy of classification. My final results of user's and producer's accuracy are howver switched between two packages.

Please, **which package correctly calculate the values for user and producer accuracy**?

Reproductible example

```
library(asbio)

# create dummy data
landsat <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2)
reference <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2)

# calculate Kappa statistics
asbio::Kappa(landsat,reference)  # Kappa(class1, reference)

# check out Kappa results
$ttl_agreement
[1] 76

$user_accuracy
1     2     3     4     5 
75.0  58.3 100.0 100.0 100.0 

$producer_accuracy
1     2     3     4     5 
50.0  87.5 100.0 100.0  60.0 

$khat
[1] 68.1

$table
       reference
class1  1 2 3 4 5
      1 3 3 0 0 0
      2 1 7 0 0 0
      3 0 0 4 0 0
      4 0 0 0 2 0
      5 0 2 0 0 3

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------   
# make the same calculation with the greenbrown package
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

library(greenbrown)  
library(strucchange)
library(raster)
library(Kendall)
library(plyr)
library(bfast)
library(zoo)

# calculate the contingency table
tab <- table(landsat, reference)   data

# let's see the tab
tab

           reference
landsat   1 2 3 4 5
        1 3 3 0 0 0
        2 1 7 0 0 0
        3 0 0 4 0 0
        4 0 0 0 2 0
        5 0 2 0 0 3

# calculate the accuracy assessement
greenbrown::AccuracyAssessment(tab)

                    1        2   3   4   5 Sum UserAccuracy
1                 3  3.00000   0   0   0   6         50.0
2                 1  7.00000   0   0   0   8         87.5
3                 0  0.00000   4   0   0   4        100.0
4                 0  0.00000   0   2   0   2        100.0
5                 0  2.00000   0   0   3   5         60.0
Sum               4 12.00000   4   2   3  25           NA
ProducerAccuracy 75 58.33333 100 100 100  NA         76.0
```

The user and producer's accuracy are **switched between two packages** ! 
Please, **which calculation and estimation of the user's and producer's accuracy is correct**?

Comment: According the definition of Producer and User accuracy, the accuracies estimated by `greenbrown` package is correct. However, overall accuracy, kappa and khat statistics is correct for `asbio` as well.

Comment: Thank you @rar, that's what I have thought.